# Xcode: how to generate .app file?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm porting my game project from Windows to OSX and I finally managed to create a working executable but the problem is I need the .app file for distribution and Xcode does't generate one, only the executable file.

Maybe I created a wrong project at the start? Is it possible to create .app file from Command Line Tool project? Should I create a new target "Applicaton"?

Here is the screenshot from my project settings: http://1.1m.yt/NwlO0PH.png

I'm new to OSX system and how everything works.

**Xcode version** 4.6

**Project Type:** C++ command line tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a `Command-Line Tool`, when you should be creating a `Cocoa Application`.

> Xcode > File > New > Project... > Cocoa Application

( <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> )

This will allow you to build an application bundle (.app)

Comment: Is it enough if I make a new Target instead of a new project?

Comment: I also use pure C++ so I am wondering if Cocoa Application is appropriate here?

Comment: @Blodyavenger: Yes, you can make a new target as well. C++ can be intermixed with Objective-C, Cocoa, C, etc. The only thing to keep in mind is the file extension needs to be specified appropriately (.mm, .cpp).

Comment: I created a new target (Cocoa Application), set it up and it works like a charm. Thank you for quick help!